# VideoJS - Change the user Status manually

Tags: html, video.js

I have a problem with VideoJS, I found the userActive and userInactive callback, that is working perfectly. But now I need to can set the user status manually in my code. So I found the `player.userActive(boolean)` method on the videojs blog but its not working.

My Code:

```
function playerAction(action) {
   console.log("Play Action - " + action);
   var player = videojs("player");

   switch(action) {
      case "play": player.play(); break;
      case "pause": player.pause(); break;
      case "useractive": player.userActive(true); break;
      default: console.log("Action " + action + " not existing");
   }
}
```

The Play and the Pause action are working perfectly, only `useractive` won't work.

The Error Message is:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'userActive'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Problem now:

VideoJS has removed this function in the minified version of the Javascript File. You have to use the `video.dev.js` to access the `player.userActive()` functionality.

I hope this will help somebody!

Comment: I was going to suggest that you should be using event listeners for this kind of thing, but reading through your example again I assume you've got a different use case. We can export userActive if it would be useful, though...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have minimized the .dev.js and the size is also ok ;) but thank you!

Comment: also to check current state/activity (`player.userActivity_`)